# C++ Type vs. Non-Type Template Deduction Question

Tags: c++, templates, template-argument-deduction

I have a question about C++ template deduction when there are two matches: one typed and the other non-typed. In the following situation:

```
// First
template<int>
void g(int a)
{
...
}

// Second
template<class A>
void g(A a)
{
...
}

int a = 1;
g(a);
```

the Second template is favored, while if the non-typed template parameter is given a default value:

```
// First
template<int m = 1>
void g(int a)
{
...
}

// Second
template<class A>
void g(A a)
{
...
}

int a = 1;
g(a);
```

the First template is favored. Why?? Which rules are in play here? Thanks.

Comment: What value should the non-type template parameter have in the first case? You seem to be conflating it with the function argument. It will not be determined from `a`.

Comment: That is actually a question from a C++ certification test. I guess that's the answer -- if the parameter value cannot be determined, the template is simply not used.

Answer (score 8):

In the first case:

```cpp
// First
template<int>
void g(int a)
{
...
}
```

is only invokable with a specified template parameter, for instance like this `g<1>(42);`. There is no way for the compiler to deduce the value to use for the `int`, so the first function does not participate in overload resolution.

In the second case there is a default value, so now both functions are part of overload resolution and then the `int` version is a closer match than deducing that `A = int`.